# How to crack forgotton KeePass password when knowing most of the password

Tags: passwords, keepass, hashcat, john-the-ripper

A few days ago I changed my KeePass password and forgot it unfortunately. It isn't that much different from the previous one, but I kept trying and trying and it says it's incorrect
I found https://www.rubydevices.com.au/blog/how-to-hack-keepass

I want to make my own wordlist so I can attact it using the dictionary attack.

- My password is something like " FaceAndBook123xxx#@xxxxxx "

--> the xxx after the 123 are 45678.. (it can also be just "123" but also "123456" I know it's max 6)

--> after "@" the xxxxx can be other things but I'm not sure, it's either "Book" , "Book" + 123 (or 1234, 12345 or 123456)

--> So I know it starts with "FaceAndBook" and contains "123" "#@" and "Book"

--> Min of 20 char, max 30

I tried Cruncher to generate a wordlist but it gave me 1844444444444444444444444 lines to generate (I don't know if it supports words instead of characters)

Anyone that can help me?

Comment: dear god I hope you really didn't just publish part of your password online … lol

Comment: If the text in your question has any relation to the actual password you're trying to recover, I *strongly* recommend changing it anywhere you've used it after you figure out what it was, and editing the question to be more generic whether you find it or not. (While it will be in the edit history, it won't be crawled).

Comment: Do you have a backup of a recent version of your KeePass container? It will work with the old password.

Comment: There's no relation to my real password with the example I provided (+ that password style hasn't been used by me on any other platform).
And unfortunately I don't have a backup, stupid mistake by me.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a combinator attack would be a good place to start.  It takes two input wordlists and tries all combinations of the two.  In your case, the "left" list would be the beginning of your known password and the "right" list would be the unknown portions.

However, Hashcat only allows two input files to a combinator attack, but you can use the standalone `combinator` utility to pre-process multiple files down to one.  For example:

```
combinator part1  part2 > part12
combinator part12 part3 > part123
...
```

In your case, the files would probably be split into the following chunks:

- The known prefix of your password
- Sequential numbers of varying lengths (`1`, `12`, `123`, ...)
- The word that may or may not be included, plus one blank line

  - The blank line is *required*, otherwise all output candidates will contain the word.  Including the blank line means that half will include it and half wont.
- Another sequential number section, just like the previous

Answer (score 1):

You could try [mod0keecrack](https://github.com/devio/mod0keecrack):

> **mod0keecrack** is a simple tool to crack/brute-force passwords of
>   KeePass 2 databases. It implements a KeePass 2 Database file parser
>   for .kdbx files, as well as decryption routines to verify if a
>   supplied password is correct. mod0keecrack only handles the encrypted
>   file format and is not able to parse the resulting plaintext database.
>   The only purpose of mod0keecrack is the brute-forcing of a KeePass 2
>   database password.